# How do I know which type of music have I created?

Tags: genre

I have created music using drums and guitar, but I do not know in which category does my music falls in. Is it jazz, pop or any other. Also if in future I create a music with a violin in addition, does the genre of music change?

Comment: could you post a sample - it might help us decide

Comment: Genres are very subjective. If you created a piece of music, you already know which musical tropes and techniques you've used and how they fit into the genres you're familiar with. As a result, you can describe your music with whatever genre or genres you think are appropriate!